# Can't Update my ADT android from 22 to v 23

Tags: android, eclipse

I can't Update my ADT as shown . as shown

" Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency."
what should I do ?!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've found out the hard way that upgrading a ADT bundle from v22.x to v23.x just doesn't work.  This was caused by changes that Google made.

I ran into this problem, and the only way to get the new ADT version is to get a new bundle.

You can see the whole thread [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72912), below is the post by a Google Project Member:

> Ok, guys, sorry about all this trouble, and we apologize for the
>   messed up releases. Here's the summary:
>
> - There is no way to update an existing ADT bundle that you might have downloaded.
> - You can do one of two options:
>
>   1. Install eclipse from eclipse.org and install ADT by pointing to the update site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
>   2. Download bundles from here:
>
> linux 64 bit vm:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> linux 32 bit vm:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
>
> mac:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> win32:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
>
> win64:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> Starting with ADT bundle 23.0.2, you should be able to update to future versions of ADT.

One more strange thing to note, they actually went back to an older version of Eclipse for these ADT bundles, and you will no longer get the nice black and green Android specific splash screen that Eclipse had before.