# Eclipse Android, Confilicting Dependency ADT 23.0.6.1720515

Tags: android, eclipse

I got message that it tells Conflicting Dependecy when i want update my ADT using Eclipse. The screen shoot of a problem in below image:

[image]

Does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270435/cant-update-my-adt-android-from-22-to-v-23/30270560#30270560

Comment: thanks Mr! its work properly after follwing you answer

Comment: Sure, no problem!  Glad you got it resolved!